# Print toString()'s from separate classes

Tags: java, tostring

I got two classes, both with one toString() each. In a third class (Main), i want to print the information from the toString()'s by only calling one of the toString()'s. Some help would be fantastic!

Main:

```
public static void print(Class1[] cls1, int index){

        System.out.println(cls1[index].toString());
}
```

Class1:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getMethod() + getMethod2();                             
}
```

Class2:

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getMethod3() + getMethod4();
}
```

One alternative I thought of was adding Class2.toString() to Class1 (I couldn't make it work):

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getMethod() + getMethod2() + Class2.toString();                             
}
```

Another idea i had was to just add the getters right into the toString in Class1 instead of using a toString (this did not work either):

```
@Override
public String toString() {
    return getMethod() + getMethod2() + Class2.getMethod3() + Class2.getMethod4();                             
}
```

Comment: Where are your instances of `Class2`?

Comment: just call the method directly from the object of that class.

Answer (score 2):

You can't refer to `toString` like this, because it's not a static method

```
Class2.toString();
```

You need an object from `Class2` class in order to use `toString` like:

```
class2Obj.toString();
```

Also that works for `Class2.getMethod3()` and `Class2.getMethod4`

```
class2Obj.getMethod3();
```

Answer (score 1):

You're first idea of adding class2's to string didn't work because to string is not a static method, so you must call it on an object. I don't really see why you can't just make a call to each one individually, but most of your problems stem from trying to make static calls to the to string methods. I wasn't sure from your question , but if class 2 extends class 1 there is an easy fix: add `super.toString()` as the first line of class 2's to string method.

Answer (score 0):

```
public Class1{

  @Override 
  public String toString(){
    return yourMethod();
  }
}

public Class2 {
  private Class1 class1;
  //getters and setters

   @Overrie
   public String toString(){
      return class1.toString() + yourMethodFromClass2();
   }
}
public class MainClass{
public static void main(String[] args){
   Class1 class1 = new Class1();
   Class2 class2 = new Class2();
   class2.setClass1(class1);
   class2.toString();

}

}
```

Now you can simply put class2.toString into some method and invoke it in your main :) also in toString or sth.